Manhwa/manhua/manga about an emperor who regresses to the past after his wife and son die in a fire
I watched a short about a manhwa/manhua/manga and really liked it but the name wasn't in the comments.
The male lead (ML) didn't have his name show up but his wife's name was Rose (according to the short) and they are happy together living a simple life; she's pregnant and they're both super happy and in-love. But then it turns out he was royalty of some kind and became the emperor. She tells him that she hates him or something and his life starts falling apart.
In the next scene I saw, their son got caught in a fire in the palace garden and his wife jumps into the fire to save their son. I think they both die and the ML kills everyone involved with the death of his family. He then regresses to when she was still pregnant and they were happy probably to save/protect them.
Does anyone know the name? I really want to read it now. For clarification, I'm pretty sure it was a fantasy story (the regression and emperor is what's making me think that at least) and maybe a romance.

What are the sci-fi / fantasy elements? How old is it?

Do you still have a link to the short?

This is The Empress of Ashes.

When Eilec wakes up in the past after slaughtering everyone who played a part in his beloved wife's death, he knows the best way to avoid making the same mistakes would be to let Rose go. Despite this, Eilec is determined to change the future with her by his side, as he can't imagine a life without her. But when Rose regains her memories and sees that Eilec has dragged her into the hellish world of nobles and their political scheming for the second time, he realizes he has made a grave mistake. The hatred and resentment that burns in her eyes are almost as hot as the fire that killed her in the past. Will Rose find it in herself to forgive her husband, or will she burn everything to ashes, including him?

The protagonist, Eilec, was a royal who married a commoner named Rose before becoming Emperor. She was unhappy with how he changed after becoming Emperor and tells him in the prologue that he disgusts her.



One of his subordinates subsequently informs him that a fire has broken out in the botanical garden and that Rose and the First Prince died after she dove in to rescue him.



Eilec snaps and kills the people he believes were responsible for the fire, before committing suicide. He then wakes up in Rose's arms and realises that he's regressed to the past, before he became Emperor.
You can read the full manhwa at Tappytoon and there's a trailer for it on YouTube.




Thank you so much I'm so excited to read this!
